# xen Server use "xl rename" VM vm-abc to vm-abc-old, and recreat a VM named vm-abc, has issues

Tags: virtual-machine, rename, xen

I have a xen Server,   a VM named vm-abc, renamed the VM to vm-abc-old. 
Now I want to create a new VM named vm-abc. get below errors:

```
----------  WARNING ---------
/usr/local/xenvm/vm-abc exists already !
```

Anyone can give some advisces? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option --force in the xen-create-image comand. But, remenber this delete the 'vm-abc' VM.